# How to plugin into grpc-java to modify code generation and add setNameOrClear(null) methods?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, protobuf-java

We are having too many issues around all this extra code for every database field with regard to

```
if(databaseObj.getName() != null)
   builder.setName(databaseObj.getName());
```

and I read square wired into protobuf adding setOrClear methods in java.  How do we do this when we generate as well using gradle?

We are using the gradle code from this page right now..

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that via `protoc_insertion_point`s. When you generate the Java code you will see comments like `// @@protoc_insertion_point(...)`. That is where the insertion will occur.

While appearing useful, this approach has serious drawbacks for .protos used in multiple projects. *All* projects using the same .proto and in the same language should use the same plugins, otherwise it causes [the diamond dependency problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem). This is why gRPC did *not* use this approach and instead generates its classes in separate files from the normal message generation. I strongly discourage against this approach, as it paints you into a corner and you don't know when you will need to "pay the piper."

To insert into a point, your plugin needs to run in the same `protoc` command-line invocation as the java builtin. Your plugin would then need to set [`CodeGeneratorResponse.file.insertion_point`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto#L135) and `content` for each file you want to inject code.

Comment: thanks again!!!  Going to do some playing around with it this weekend.